# Receive postMessage from chrome new tab extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup (that is not made by me) that sends a postMessage for a login callback.

In the new tab page (that opened the popup), I am unable to receive this message.

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  console.log("MESSAGE RECEIVED!");
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

^This does not work.

(I am aware of the following API, chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal , but since the popup does not send a message via the chrome runtime, I cannot use this)

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Post message is a back and forth deal. Try this.

```js
/* in the extension */
var description = {};
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
  desc: 'some value'
}, function(response) {
  description.value = response.details;
  /* do your thing */
});


/* in the content script (your popup) */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var desc = request.desc;
  sendResponse(desc);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, this was not clear in the post. But it is not my popup, it is a pop up from a third party, used for a login flow, which I cannot control.